# Can anyone share a sample .lldbinit file?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb, alias, lldb

Does anyone out there have an .lldbinit file they can share?  It would be really useful to see a few commands defined, just to understand the syntax.

Comment: Go to github.com and search for lldbinit to find files, cheers...

Answer (score 5):

Another examples can be found on GitHub https://github.com/search?q=lldbinit. One of few from https://github.com/bsmt/lldbinit/blob/master/lldbinit

```
# wish lldb supported colors :/
settings set prompt [lldb]$

# breakpoint shortcuts
# break on function/method/selector: b -n name
# break on C/C++ method: b -M method
# break on selector: b -S selector:here:
# break on address: b -a 0xfeedface
command alias b breakpoint set
command alias bd breakpoint disable
command alias be breakpoint enable
command alias bdel breakpoint delete
command alias bcommand breakpoint command add
command alias commands breakpoint command list

# jump aliases
# jump 0xfeedface
command alias jump register write pc
command alias jmp register write pc
command alias j register write pc

# fix p/s
# p/s rsi
command alias p/s register read

# fscript (cbf to fix fscript anywhere)
command alias f_init p (char)[[NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/Library/Frameworks/FScript.framework"] load]
command alias f_start p (void)[FScriptMenuItem insertInMainMenu]

command alias return thread return
```

Comment: `wish lldb supported colors :/ ` I found it "almost works":

see https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40200 color prompt causes wrong indentation of cmds (with `settings set prompt "\033[31m(lldb)\033[0m "`)

Comment: wish lldb supported newline in prompt (`settings set prompt "\n(lldb) "`)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the examples in the lldb repository:

- [bin-utils](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/customization/bin-utils/)
- [pwd-cd-and-system](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/customization/pwd-cd-and-system/)

Comment: links need updating

Comment: moved to [bin-utils](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/examples/customization/bin-utils) and [pwd-cd-and-system](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/examples/customization/pwd-cd-and-system)